# Facebook FXBML since Yesterday not rendering (IFRAME Canvas)

Tags: facebook

since yesterday is my app not rendering the xfbml Tags (name and picture). Iam using the new JavaScript SDK inside an Canvas-Iframe Application.

Firebug tells me the following inside the console:

```
Get: http://0.channel20.facebook.com/x/3332504234/true/p_1348362044=0
```

And after a while:

```
 XFBML tags failed to render in 30000ms.
```

Does someone has the same problems, or know why this happens?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ie was getting the same issue for a long and able to resolve it just now.

All and all you just need to wrap the entire XFBML code in JS/jQuery and parse it as shown below:

```
    $('#like').html('<fb:like href="'+url+ '" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="65" action="like" font="segoe ui" colorscheme="light" />')
    if (typeof FB  != "undefined"){
        FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('like'))
    }
```

HTML code:

```
    <div id="like">
      </div>
```

You are done.

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why this works? Would love to know.

Comment: Chakrit, not doing much here just rendering the FBML tag through FB.XFBML.parse() after checking whether we have the FB API loaded or not.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook have recently released a major update to their API, including changes to their Javascript and XFBML features. Not sure when they were deprecating old interfaces, but you may be caught up in the crossfire if you're not using the new API.

The new API is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: it is the new api... it is very hard to find actual news when something is buggy..