# Invite a friend via Facebook is failing all of a sudden

Tags: facebook, xfbml

I have the Facebook invite feature on a site that I am working on and all of a sudden it stopped working. Here is what I have:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({ appId: '145554402127660', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });

 };
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<fb:serverFbml width="565px">
   <script type="text/fbml">
   <fb:fbml>
    <fb:request-form method='POST' invite=true
     type='Our site'
    action='http://somesite.com/step3'
     content='this is the place you want to be'>
     <fb:multi-friend-selector cols=3
      actiontext="Invite your friends to join you our site"
     />
     </fb:request-form>
    </fb:fbml>
    </script>

</fb:serverFbml>
```

This worked before, but now for some reason I always get this error:

```
1 XFBML tags failed to render in 30000ms.
```

Any ideas on what is happening and why this stopped all of a sudden? Also, if there is a new way of doing this, maybe with the Graph API, I would highly appreciate info about it.

Comment: is the `action` parameter is pointing to the same domain used in your facebook app setting?

Comment: yes the action has the same domain

Answer (score 0):

got namespace xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" ?

Comment: what do you mean...where does that go

Answer (score 0):

the answer is here - [Facebook FXBML since Yesterday not rendering (IFRAME Canvas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863390/facebook-fxbml-since-yesterday-not-rendering-iframe-canvas)

You'll have to call FB.XFBML.parse after FB.init is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The newest way of doing this is through the Requests 2.0 Dialog, part of the Graph API. It's about 2 months "old". It works through the javascript API.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464