# Page reloads after loading a connected FB account using Facebook Login Plugin

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have the following code:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="370" max-rows="5" scope="email">Log In with Facebook</fb:login-button>
</body>
</html>
```

1. I log into the app using Facebook.
2. The page refreshes showing me that I'm logged in.
3. If I refresh or load the the page again then Facebook will load the plugin. After around 10 seconds, the page will reload.

Did I initialize wrong or is this simply how Facebook does things?

EDIT:
I sometimes get the following error:

> 1 XFBML tags failed to render in 30000ms.

Found a temporary fix from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182542/968219

I don't know why this works but I'm glad it fixes it. Does anyone know a better fix?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a channel file

```
FB.init({
            appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            channelUrl : '//WWW.MY_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
```

the channel file would only include:

```
 <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

reference:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the xfbml rendering is not working properly, try using the HTML version.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" show-faces="true" width="370" max-rows="5" scope="email">Login with Facebook</div>
```

or you can also just build your own login button and bind it to this:

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

Comment: Can I still use and subscribe to `xfbml.render` when I use the HTML version?

Comment: yes you can and it would fire the event nonetheless I'm not sure what would you use it for. is it to be used as an onload delegate?

Comment: Some elements on the page can only be shown after the plugin renders.